# Won't recognize JSX code in React Native app?

Tags: react-native

In my Card.js I have this code:

```
const Card = props => {
  return (
    <View style={{...styles.card, ...props.style }}>{props.children}</View>
  );
};




const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  card: {
    shadowColor: 'black',
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
    shadowRadius: 6,
    shadowOpacity: 0.26,
    elevation: 8,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    padding: 20,
    borderRadius: 10
  }
});
```

And heres the other component:

```
import Card from '../components/Card';

const StartGameScreen = props => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>Start a New Game!</Text>
      <Card style={styles.inputContainer}>
        <Text>Select a Number</Text>
        <TextInput />
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <Button title="Reset" onPress={() => {}} />
          <Button title="Confirm" onPress={() => {}} />
        </View>
      </Card>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  
  inputContainer: {
    width: 300,
    maxWidth: '80%',
    alignItems: 'center'
  }
 
});

export default StartGameScreen;
```

When I debug my app JSX I wrote in Card.js doesnt apply. Does anyone know how to fix this?
It shows no errors at but it still wont apply style property I wrote in Card.js?

Comment: Have you imported react in both the files?

Comment: I found a solution.

 <View style={[styles.card, props.style]}>{props.children}</View>

Comment: did you import StyleSheet ?

Comment: Then post it as an answer, could be helpful to others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the construct

```js
{{...styles.X, ...styles.Y}}
```

is not working in react-native is because the `StyleSheet.create()` function is **not** returning a plain JS object. Thus, we can not apply the `spread` operator here.

Indeed, notice that the following will work.

```js
// or whatever style objects
{{...{margin: 10}, ...{backgroundColor: "red"}}}
```

Since we are passing the styles as plain JS objects.

However, as you have noticed yourself, the usual way to combine multiple styles from a stylesheet inline is using an array.

```js
{[styles.X, styles.Y]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found solution.

```
 <View style={[styles.card, props.style]}>{props.children}</View>
```

Comment: You should mark this as the answer

Comment: Still don't know why it won't work in the first example, if anyone knows would be great to know .